# How can I query a token balance for a specific account through RPC?

Tags: rpc

I currently retrieve the native XTZ balance through the /<block_id>/context/contracts/<contract_id>/balance endpoint (documented here https://tezos.gitlab.io/active/rpc.html#get-block-id-context-contracts-contract-id-balance but wasn't able to find how to do so for token accounts.
I want to check the token balance for a specific account

Comment: It would help if you could tell us which token you want to use. There are two main token standards, FA1.2 and FA2, and the interfaces offered by these standards are a bit different.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is to use the TzKT API: https://api.tzkt.io/#operation/Tokens_GetTokenBalances

Answer (score 0):

Octez has two helper RPC endpoints for calling views on smart contract:

- `/chains/main/blocks/head/helpers/scripts/run_view`: Simulate a call to a view following the TZIP-4 standard.
- `/chains/main/blocks/head/helpers/scripts/run_script_view`:  Simulate a call to a Michelson view.

If your contract follows the FA1.2 or FA2 token standard, you want to use the first one (`run_view`) because these standards predate Michelson views. The documentation of this RPC endpoint can be obtained by `octez-client` as follows:

```
$ octez-client rpc list /chains/main/blocks/head/helpers/scripts/run_view

Available services:
  
  - POST /chains/main/blocks/head/helpers/scripts/run_view
      Simulate a call to a view following the TZIP-4 standard. See
      https://gitlab.com/tezos/tzip/-/blob/master/proposals/tzip-4/tzip-4.md#view-entrypoints.
```

That being said I agree with @dmirg; if you can use the API of an indexer such as TzKT it will be simpler for you than relying on Octez RPCs.